# How to clean a baseball cap?

Tags: cleaning, clothing, laundry

I dropped a baseball cap in a puddle of mud. I'm afraid to drop it in the laundry. How can I best clean it?

Comment: never had a problem with the hat going in the washer..

Comment: The one time I dropped a hat in the washer, the bill was shattered.

Comment: [-1, does not show any research effort.](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20clean%20a%20baseball%20hat) Also, flagged for closure, how-to does not seem to require a hack and need for out-of-the-box solution has not been identified. More constructively, [these exist](http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/product/perfectcurve-reg-cap-washer/1017230018), and have existed for quite a few decades.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you afraid that just putting it in the washing machine can damage your cap or just don't have a washing machine, you can fill your washing bowl with hot water and add some soap or... shampoo :) Scrub your cap with some brush.

Images from wikihow:

> [image]
>
> [source](http://pad1.whstatic.com/images/thumb/7/77/Wash-a-Baseball-Cap-by-Hand-Step-3.jpg/760px-Wash-a-Baseball-Cap-by-Hand-Step-3.jpg)
>
> [image]
>
> [source](http://pad1.whstatic.com/images/thumb/0/05/Wash-a-Baseball-Cap-by-Hand-Step-3Bullet1.jpg/760px-Wash-a-Baseball-Cap-by-Hand-Step-3Bullet1.jpg)

After washing, remove the soap from your cap with water and dry it with a towel or with a fan (it is more effective). If you don't have a fan, you can put some paper in the cap - it will absorb the water.

Comment: This is exactly what I do periodically with all my hats. Keeps them clean and doesn't destroy their shape. Also make sure to air dry after rinsing.

Answer (score 4):

The cap has no oil stain, which is good. I recommend power washing with a hose. Because fabric on the bill of the cap is not flexible, the dirt cannot be worked out, and rubbing the bill of the cap may set the dirt. Power washing with hot water will flush the dirt out. Add soap and rinse the soap through the stiff parts of the cap, then rinse again to get the remainder of soap out. If there is no oil or grease component, all should come out.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to do is not wet it - let it dry out completely, take a stiff brush (something like a vegetable washing brush or a stiff nail brush), go outside with the cap and scrub at the mud till you've got most of it off. Provided its only mud, most will come off - my cap's black, so that's all I need to do, although if it still looks a bit 'grey', I rub it over with a damp cloth afterwards. If yours isn't black, you may then need to do something 'wet' as suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in the top rack of the dishwasher.  You can rubber band the bill around a suitable glass or bowl to retian its shape.  In fact, they even sell plastic molds for hats specifically for this.